# How to install new packages in a non root running container?

Tags: docker, containers, alpine-linux

I need to install simple packages such as curl inside a running container but I face this error:

```
~ $ apk add curl
ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied
ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission denied
```

I know how to chnage the user in a Dockerfile but I don't have access to the docker file and I need to do it while I am inside the container or when opening a terminal inside the container. I tried to use `--user=` but didn't work:

```
kubectl exec -n kube-system --user="root" -it tiller-deploy-75f6c87b87-xtpxl /bin/ash
error: auth info "root" does not exist
```

How I can get root access or install curl?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Is your user sudoer?
Run this command:

```
sudo apk add curl
```

And if the above command didn't work, run this command.

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME apk add curl
```

Comment: I did not downvote even though I was tempted to. You answered the question alright but your answer neglects the rest/main body of the question and thus your answer should not be marked correct. @Avarf stated his tries telling you he tried both your solutions already (sudo should generally not be installed in a container anyways). The issue he has is not solveable from within the container. He used `kubectl`, so an accepted answer should use that information.

Answer (score 8):

Use kubectl describe pod ... to find the node running your Pod and the container ID (docker://...)

SSH into the node

```
run docker exec -u root ID -- /bin/bash
```

Comment: Sound advice and it worked like a charm. Docker as root works kubectl with suer root does not. Any idea why?

Comment: Would be helpful if you gave instructions on how to ssh into the pod

Comment: This does not answer the case when a user 'root' does not exist in the target container, you'll still get "error: auth info "root" does not exist"