# How to run bash as user root on alpine images with docker? su: must be suid to work properly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, kong

**Edit:**
The answer is so clear. One may use the flag `--user root` when entering the container.

```
docker exec -it --user root mycontainername bash                 or sh
```

---

I just downloaded this official docker hub's 1.5.0-alpine image for a service (Kong API Gateway) and now I can not run apk commands to install nano, for instance.

Before, I just had to enter the container

```
docker exec -it kong sh
```

or

```
docker-compose exec kong sh
```

and I was able to run commands like `apk update` or `apk add nano`, for instance.

But now I get these errors

```
$ apk update                                                                                                                                   
ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied                                                                                                
ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission denied

$ apk add nano
ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied
ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission denied
```

I also tried to run sudo and su... but I got

```
$ su
su: must be suid to work properly
$ su root
su: must be suid to work properly
$ suid
sh: suid: not found
```

Will I really need to build my own custom image? I was using the official one and it was working fine.

Comment: Building your own custom image is a very routine part of using Docker, and I wouldn't shy away from it.  (If you do succeed in `apk add ...` as you've shown, that work will get lost as soon as you delete the container; writing that down in a Dockerfile is a good way to make it happen repeatably.)

Comment: You are right. But it's convenient to use `apk add` or `apt install` inside one container and not persist those packages added/installed. Just for debugging something in that moment.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can run a command within the container as root using `--user root`. To get a shell:

```
docker exec -it --user root kong sh
```

Comment: if im not able to connect with root? error: auth info "root" does not exist
there's any way to create it?

Comment: @NoamiA That sounds like a problem with `kubectl` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221955/how-to-install-new-packages-in-a-non-root-running-container)).

Answer (score 1):

In your docker file you can use the `chmod` command to set the SUID bit in the `su` command, located at `/file`
like this `RUN chmod u+s /file` The `u+s` option specifies that the SUID bit should be set on the file. The `u` refers to the permissions for the owner of the file, and the `+s` means to add the SUID bit to the file's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You must use $CONTAINER_ID :

```
docker exec -it --user root $CONTAINER_ID /bin/sh
```

Comment: [This is simply not true](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).  It's perfectly valid to use the container name, e.g. `docker run --name ubuntu_bash --rm -i -t ubuntu bash` then `docker exec -it ubuntu_bash bash`.